# Main.Show() Parameter is not valid

Tags: bunifu

*NOTE: I'm using Bunifu but this error also occurred whenever I changed the font to Century Gothic or any font that's not default.*

Here is my code:

```
Form form = new Main();
form.ShowDialog(new Main());
this.Hide();
```

The problem:

Anytime any graphical update happens on the Main form it causes the error "Parameter is not valid."

Things I've tried:

```
this.ShowDialog(new Main());
Application.Run(new Main());
this.Show(new Main());
form.Show();
form.ShowDialog();
```

Full Error:

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath.AddArc(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, Single startAngle, Single sweepAngle)
   at Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuThinButton2.method_0(Graphics graphics_0, Rectangle rectangle_0, Int32 int_4, Pen pen_0, Color color_6)
   at Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuThinButton2.Refresh()
   at Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuThinButton2.BunifuThinButton2_MouseEnter(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuThinButton2.label1_MouseEnter(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Label.OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, Int32 wparam, Int32 lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at Larray_s_Proxy_Tool__v1._0_.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Jardi\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Larray's Proxy Tool (v1.0)\Larray's Proxy Tool (v1.0)\Form1.cs:line 63
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: `form.ShowDialog(this);`

Comment: That created an error in Program.cs, "Application.Run(new Form1());" Line 19.

Comment: Where's that `this.Hide();` coming from.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to hide the current form and open Main.
"Form form = new Main();
 form.Show(this);
 this.Hide();"

Comment: You drawing anything in a paint event?  Post that.

Comment: Nope. For some reason anytime I try anything graphical (changing fonts, using themes, etc) it fails on this project. I just created a UI without anything too fancy and it seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: If you don't have any drawing code, then the Bunifu framework you are using could be the culprit.  It's trying to draw an arc from a MouseEnter event and the parameter it is using doesn't work.  Try deleting Label1 and see if the problem persists.

Comment: This Bunifu framework you are using is not very resilient.  If you sneeze a bit too loud then it will crash like this.  It in particular does not seem to handle a control well whose Width or Height is 0.  What it *should* do is not draw anything at all, but it plows on anyway.  Graphics.AddArc() will fail like this when its Rectangle has width or height of 0.  Why it is 0 is not obvious from the stack trace, but hiding a form is a good way to do so.